# Troubles with filtering observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I need to create new array, that will contain only items with value "pos" equal to zero or greater. My source array of objects:

```
self.appendableData = ko.observableArray([
    {text: "some text 1", pos: -1},
    {text: "some text 2", pos: 0},
    {text: "some text 3", pos: 1},
]);
```

trying to filter it

```
self.appendableDataToView = ko.computed(function () {
    return ko.utils.arrayFilter(self.appendableData(), function (item) {
        return item.pos >= 0;
    });
});
```

result: empty array

```
console.log(self.appendableDataToView())

[];
```

=(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need `appendableData` to be a variable

```
self.appendableData = ko.observableArray();
```

instead of

```
self.appendableData() = ko.observableArray();
```